# react-native with expo problem with facebook ads

Tags: facebook, react-native, ads, expo, facebook-audience-network

I have error when try to display Interstitial from fb:
The SDK version in the ad request is no longer supported for new apps. Please upgrade to one of the latest versions of the SDK.

Do you have info if it will be fixed (updated fb sdk) in expo 32 release?
When will be expo 32 release?

**UPDATE 2019.01.10**:

I found [this](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1989#issuecomment-449920468) answer, but it works only with ExpoKit but i dont want detach from expo.

Answer (score 0):

For react native cli not expo you may be forget to add this below line in android/app/build.gradle under dependencies section

`implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:latest.release'`