# How to setup Facebook ads using Expo?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, react-native, expo

I am using https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook-ads for adding Facebook ads to my app. I am following the documentation properly, but Facebook ads are not visible on my app home screen.

BottomBannerAd.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { FacebookAds } from 'expo';
const { AdIconView, AdMediaView } = FacebookAds;

class AdComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <AdMediaView />
        <AdTriggerView>
          <Text>{this.props.nativeAd.bodyText}</Text>
        </AdTriggerView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default FacebookAds.withNativeAd(AdComponent);
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, TextInput, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View, 
TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

import { FacebookAds } from 'expo';
import AdComponent from '../components/BottomBannerAd';
const adsManager = new FacebookAds.NativeAdsManager('xxxxxxxxxxx', 10);


import {
    AdMobBanner,
    AdMobInterstitial,

    AdMobRewarded
} from "expo";

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
render(){
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
...
<View style={styles.tabBarInfoContainer}>
<AdComponent adsManager={adsManager} />
</View>
</View>
)
}
}
```

I have a view component that holds the ad component. That view component works well when I add Google ads, but not working for Facebook ads.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to enter an actual device ID for testing, I wasn't able to get it working otherwise.

[image: setting up ID]

Your code above should generate something like this (attachment below), but only on the active device.

[image]

The normal way of testing should be by adding a
`FacebookAds.AdSettings.addTestDevice(FacebookAds.AdSettings.currentDeviceHash);` to your code, but it didn't work (for me at least).

To get an IDFA id on an iPhone, download DeviceId (by AppsFlyer) from the AppStore and also disable Limit Ad Tracking in your Privacy > Advertising settings.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where can I find the code of "currentDeviceHash" ? I want to try it using a real Android app code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - [react-native with expo problem with facebook ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53836535/react-native-with-expo-problem-with-facebook-ads)

I'm having the same issue. It appears FB ads are broken in the current expo builds.