# FacebookAds: The SDK version in the ad request is no longer supported for new apps

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-ads-api

expo SDK Version: 33, 34, 35 
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android/iOS 
Using expo-ads-facebook

I’m trying to integrate FacebookAds into my new app, and after the first run of the app I get:

The SDK version in the ad request is no longer supported for new apps. Please upgrade to one of the latest versions of the SDK

If I run the app again, I will get this error message:

> Ad was re-loaded too frequently

The weird part is that my other app works perfect and displays ads with exactly the same configuration and setup. What it could be?

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App Name",
    "slug": "app",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "34.0.0",
    "facebookAppId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "facebookDisplayName": "App Name",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.5",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "icon": "./assets/ios-icon.png",
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.com.com"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.com.com",
      "versionCode": 5,
      "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "backgroundColor": "#445d99",
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/foreground.png"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The SDK version in the ad request is no longer supported for new apps. Please upgrade to one of the latest versions of the SDK

Comment: Probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53836535/react-native-with-expo-problem-with-facebook-ads

Comment: @Oleg, but that duplicate has no answers.

Comment: Did you try with expo 35?

Comment: I am tried on expo 35 but same result basic problem is Facebook SDK 5.1.0 it need  to update (latest version 5.5.0 )